# TF-IDF algorithm in gremlin

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tf-idf

I am stuck trying to calculate [TF_IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) in my rexster graph database. Here is what I got:

Say I have a graph consisting of a set of vertices representing terms, T, and a set of vertices representing documents, D.

There are edges, E, between terms in T and documents in D. Each edge has a term frequency, tf.

Eg. (pseudocode):

```
#x, y, and z are arbitrary IDs.
T(x) - E(y) -> D(z)

E(y).tf = 20

T(x).outE()
  => A set of edges.

T(x).outE().inV()
  => A list of Documents, a subset of D
```

How could I write a germlin script that calculates the TF_IDF when I am trying to do the following?

- A: Given one term **t**, calculate TF_IDF of each Document directly related to **t**.
- B: Given a set of terms **Ts**, calculate sum of the TF_IDF of each document in `Ts.outE().inV()` in relation to each applicable term in **Ts**.

---

What I have thus far:

```
#I know this does not work
term = g.v(404)
term.outE().inV().as('docs').path().
groupBy{it.last()}{
  it.findAll{it instanceof Edge}.
  collect{it.getProperty('frequency')} #I would actually like to use augmented frequency (aka frequency_of_t_in_document / max_frequency_of_any_t_in_document) 
}.collect{d,tf-> [d, 
  tf * ??log(??g.V.has('isDocument') / docs.count() ?? ) ??
]}

#I feel I am close, but I can't quite make this work.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably haven't covered the part

> B: ...in relation to each applicable term in **Ts**.

...but the rest should work as expected. I wrote a little helper function that accepts single terms as well as multiple terms:

```
tfidf = { g, terms, N ->
  def closure = {
    def paths = it.outE("occursIn").inV().path().toList()
    def numPaths = paths.size()
    [it.getProperty("term"), paths.collectEntries({
      def title = it[2].getProperty("title")
      def tf = it[1].getProperty("frequency")
      def idf = Math.log10(N / numPaths)
      [title, tf * idf]
    })]
  }
  def single = terms instanceof String
  def pipe = single ? g.V("term", terms) : g.V().has("term", T.in, terms)
  def result = pipe.collect(closure).collectEntries()
  single ? result[terms] : result
}
```

Then I took the Wikipedia example to test it:

```
g = new TinkerGraph()

g.createKeyIndex("type", Vertex.class)
g.createKeyIndex("term", Vertex.class)

t1 = g.addVertex(["type":"term","term":"this"])
t2 = g.addVertex(["type":"term","term":"is"])
t3 = g.addVertex(["type":"term","term":"a"])
t4 = g.addVertex(["type":"term","term":"sample"])
t5 = g.addVertex(["type":"term","term":"another"])
t6 = g.addVertex(["type":"term","term":"example"])

d1 = g.addVertex(["type":"document","title":"Document 1"])
d2 = g.addVertex(["type":"document","title":"Document 2"])

t1.addEdge("occursIn", d1, ["frequency":1])
t1.addEdge("occursIn", d2, ["frequency":1])
t2.addEdge("occursIn", d1, ["frequency":1])
t2.addEdge("occursIn", d2, ["frequency":1])
t3.addEdge("occursIn", d1, ["frequency":2])
t4.addEdge("occursIn", d1, ["frequency":1])
t5.addEdge("occursIn", d2, ["frequency":2])
t6.addEdge("occursIn", d2, ["frequency":3])

N = g.V("type","document").count()

tfidf(g, "this", N)
tfidf(g, "example", N)
tfidf(g, ["this", "example"], N)
```

**Output:**

```
gremlin> tfidf(g, "this", N)
==>Document 1=0.0
==>Document 2=0.0
gremlin> tfidf(g, "example", N)
==>Document 2=0.9030899869919435
gremlin> tfidf(g, ["this", "example"], N)
==>this={Document 1=0.0, Document 2=0.0}
==>example={Document 2=0.9030899869919435}
```

I hope this already helps.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: I will give this a go as soon as I get back to where my testing-environment is set up! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: I am getting some trouble with this. I doubt it actually have to do with the implementation itself. I am running Titan 0.4.2, and I get the following error: `WARNING: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tinkerpop.rexster.protocol.msg.ErrorResponseMessage cannot be cast to org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.WritableMessage *stack_trace*`. Any idea how to approach this? I tried all the parts by them selves, and they seem to work..

Comment: This error had to do with the last line of the tfidf method: `single ? result[terms] : result`